# How to send the same variable from php to two different php pages using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I have these 4 pages and works fine, but now i need to send the "word" typed in the input field at (index.php) to another page (pag2.php) at the same time it sends to (pag1.php) using this javascript code at (script.php).

index.php

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="word" id="word" onkeyup="getSugest(this.value);">
</form>
<div class='search'><img ..... searching.gif></div>
<div id="sugest">
<div id="resultIndex"></div>
<div id="buttonsIndex">
<ul>
<?
for($i=1; $i<=page; $i++;){
echo "<li id='".$i."'>".$i."</li>";
}
?>
<ul>
</div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
    function getSugest(value){
    if(value != ""){
        if (callPage1(value) || callPage2(value)) {
         var data1 = callPage1(value);
         var data2 = callPage2(value);
         //var combinedData = combine as data1 and data2 as you want
         $("#sugest").html(combinedData); 
        } else {
         $("#sugest").html("Theres nothing in DB!"); 
        }
    }
}

function callPage1(value) {
    $.post("pag1.php",{word:value},function(data){
            if(data != ""){
                return data;
            }
            else{
                false;
            }
        });
}

function callPage2(value) {
    $.post("pag2.php",{word:value},function(data){
            if(data != ""){
                return data;
            }
            else{
                false;
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showLoader(){
        $('.search').fadeIn(200);
    }
    function hideLoader(){
        $('.search').fadeOut(200);
    };
    $("#buttonIndex li").click(function(){
        showLoader();

        $("#buttonIndex li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#D8543A'});

        $("#resultIndex").load("pag1.php?page=" + this.id, hideLoader);

        return false;
    });
    $("#buttonCar li").click(function(){
        showLoader();

        $("#buttonCar li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#D8543A'});

        $("#resultCar").load("pag2.php?page=" + this.id, hideLoader);

        return false;
    });
    $("#1").css({'background-color' : '#D8543A'});
    showLoader();
    $("#resultIndex").load("pag1.php?page=1", hideLoader);
    $("#resultCar").load("pag2.php?page=1", hideLoader);

});
```

pag1.php

```
$word = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['word']));
echo "Word is: ".$word;
//here is the php and mysql querys to return the result
```

pag2.php

```
$word = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['word']));
echo "Word is: ".$word;
//here is the php and mysql querys to return the result
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean "to another page at the same time"?  What are you having problems with? Just add another `$.post`. As for: "is this the best way"  I'd suggest *not* using inline JavaScript, and using `$('#word').keyup` to bind the event.

Comment: Your `getSugest` is missing some `}`s and `)`s.

Comment: Thanks for correct me. I think now is best explained. I already tried "just add another $.post", but didnt work. Could you send me an example please?

Comment: How did it not work?  What was the issue?

Comment: I created the same $.post just like this one, making it two block of codes just the same, only changing the page name from pag1.php to pag2.php. And when i go to the pag2.php does not appear the word. I mean, the variable doesnt go to the pag2.php. Does not display erros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline functions, use jQuery's native methods instead:

```
$(function(){
   $('#word').keyup(function(){
      if(this.value) {
         $.post("pag1.php", { word: value }, function(data) {
            if(data){
               $("#suggest").html(data);
            } else {
               $("#suggest").html("Theres nothing in DB!");
            }
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. What do i need to put instead of onkeyup="pegarSugest(this.value);"

Comment: You just remove that. `$('#word').keyup(function(){...` does the equivalent of `onkeyup="...` but in a cleaner manner.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example scenario [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/multiple-ajax-requests-with-jquery.html)

You can implement a method for each call, and after calling all of them, you can combine their results

You can also have a look at my sample code for reproduce your scenario (modify it according to your needs)

```
function getSugest(value){
    if(value != ""){
        if (callPage1(value) || callPage2(value)) {
         var data1 = callPage1(value);
         var data2 = callPage2(value);
         //var combinedData = combine as data1 and data2 as you want
         $("#sugest").html(combinedData); 
        } else {
         $("#sugest").html("Theres nothing in DB!"); 
        }
    }
}

function callPage1(value) {
    $.post("pag1.php",{word:value},function(data){
            if(data != ""){
                return data;
            }
            else{
                false;
            }
        });
}

function callPage2(value) {
    $.post("pag2.php",{word:value},function(data){
            if(data != ""){
                return data;
            }
            else{
                false;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the example you sent is very complex and will change much of my code, i would like to maintain the structure. Could you write an example of separating it in methods? cheers

Comment: cucuzoa, i really appreciate your help, and i think its nearly there. When i changed my code for this one, and typed a word inside of the input box, it shows me only the message "Theres nothing in DB!". Do i need to change anything in the others pages? In the pag1.php and pag2.php i keep calling the variable "word" as i did before? If so we need some adjustment in the code. cheers man

Comment: I updated the conditional logic in the code. && to || . So, this means, if there is valid response data at least one page, you will write it to page, else, you will show error message. Could you please try new version of code?

Comment: Still the same. Only show the message: "Theres nothing in DB!"

Comment: You got no data from both page?

Comment: yep.. no data! The idea of ur code is much more interactive and clever than what i have in the script of this post.. let me tell u how does my script works now. At the moment i can get the data from the input in (index.php) with the function 'onkeyup="getSugest(this.value)' (note that is no submit botton "it is dynamic, whiling am typing it is searching into the DB"), ok. My script on javascript get the variable and send it to another page (pag1.php) this page has the select statement.

Comment: I assume that you send 2 request at same time and combine 2 response into one array or variable.And show combined data into suggest div

Comment: Nope, i send 1 request from the input in  the index.php to the page script.js and the javascript code send the "word" (typed in index.php input field) to two different pages (pag1.php and pag2.php). I need to see the same word typed in both (pag1.php and pag2.php) using echo or <div>.

Comment: Ok, that is what i tried to say. And what do you do after sending page1 and page 2?

Comment: Its ok. I send it back to the index.php retrieving the sql result according to the word typed

Comment: page1 and page 2 included in index.php?

Comment: yep. I include them with javascript also, something like this: `$("#pag1").load("pag1.php");`
`$("#pag2").load("pag2.php");`

and in the index.php:
`<div id='pag1'></div>`
`<div id='pag2'></div>`

Comment: I confused now, You are including pag1.php and in your javascript there is an ajax call to those pages?

Comment: Ok i will update the post, in general what i am trying to do is a dynamic search engineering in my DB. But i am using the javascript to make a pagination in the result. Let me tell you the idea, when the user open the index.php appear the input text box and all result below and its pagination. When he types any letter it shows dynamically the results of the searching and its equivalent pagination. Got it?

Comment: Like google.I go it, bu your question is a bit different from what you want. You doont need to use 2 pages for this.One view(here is probably index.php) and one controller(ex. getresult.php) .When user type into textbox, you will send request to the getresult.php and write the response into the desired page with pagination

Comment: Yep u're right.. but the problem is that i need the pagination working on both situation. When the page index.php is load and when somebody types a letter. I know that the easiest way was using keyup from jQuery. But i dont know how to make the pagination working on both situation when i use keyup method. By the way i updated the post!

Comment: I'm starting to think about changing my code to use keyup and then think of a way to make pagination work. I think thats what google do!